# File download on page refresh php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

We have a web page to make that has 7 sections with a download button which will trigger a pop up form ( One form for all sections). After the form is submitted it will go to an external module(not in our control) and return back to the same web page using retURl in form.

What we want is to start file download after we return to the page after form submission.

How can i determine which button from which section was clicked to start file download of that specific section as the page will be refreshed.

Already given thought to jquery or session(php) but as the page will refresh we think the data will be erased.

Please help find a solution. Thank you

Comment: If you can pass them a callback URL, then you can pass button click info that way. Otherwise, the only other options are cookies/session. which are only cleared on refresh if they expire or are manually cleared.

Comment: The page is going to get refreshed as form data is going to external url

Comment: Indeed, but your return URL could be like this for each section: http://original-url.com/?downloadSection=1 Then on return, you would know users had clicked section 1 ... 2 ...etc The other option is to set a session value, $_SESSION['section'] = 1; And use that if set to start download. The problem with sessions is they require storage server side for functionality that could me made available via callback url?

Comment: but the thing is all the sections are going to call a common form, so how will we set return url? If each section had their own form then your solution above would be great. well the sessions part we didn't understand.

Comment: I'd recommend updating your question with an example section list and the code your are using to submit. Answers from myself and potentially others can then be provided to demonstrate how you can use JavaScript to submit a form dynamically modifying the parameters to what section a user has clicked... If that makes sense.